# git - apply a commit on another branch to the working copy

Tags: git

So I have a commit that has a helpful code change but it's on another branch.

I would like to apply this commit in the other branch to my working copy on my current branch (not as another commit).

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Thought I'd share this is related to my previous question but specific to working copy:
[git cherry picking one commit to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777547/git-cherry-picking-one-commit-to-another-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Cherry-Pick to working copy without commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333383/git-cherry-pick-to-working-copy-without-commit)

Answer (score 349, accepted):

#### How to add the desired commit(s) into different branches.

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1> --no-commit`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit(s) at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one. If you want a single commit to use a single SHA-1

[image]

---

#### `cherry-pick` without commiting

By default `git cherry-pick` **commit** your changes, so if you wish to cherry-pick without committing all the changes simply add the `-n` flag

This will allow you to review the changes and commit them manually if you wish or abort it if you run into too many conflicts.

```
git cherry-pick -n <hash>
```

---

#### `cherry-pick` a merge commit

In case you needed to cherry-pick a merge instead of a commit, use the `-m` flag

```
#
# In this case, we select the [1] first parent in the commit
# Use git show <hash> to see a list of available parents
# 
git cherry-pick -m 1 <hash>
```

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: Thanks! For both the clear & well-formatted text, and the charming diagram.
If you write a book, I'll buy it ;-)

Comment: The question explicitly mentions "not as another commit" while your answer explicitly mentions "create a new commit with this change". What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing the no commit flag

Comment: That even works for remote commits as long as your local repository knows about them (perform a `git fetch remote` to refresh)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is somewhat misleading that you quote "[...] creates a new commit [...]", just below a command containing `--no-commit`, which prevents the default commit from happening.

Comment: This is better than the official documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `one...three` will grab commits `two` and `three`, since the first one is excluded. So we must look at its parent commit to do something like `zero...three`.

Comment: Cheap upvotes for hand-drawn circles O.o

Answer (score 50):

You can still use the `git cherry-pick` command.  See `git cherry-pick --help`:

```
   -n, --no-commit
       Usually the command automatically creates a sequence of
       commits. This flag applies the changes necessary to
       cherry-pick each named commit to your working tree and the
       index, without making any commit. In addition, when this
       option is used, your index does not have to match the HEAD
       commit. The cherry-pick is done against the beginning state
       of your index.
```

So you can just `git cherry-pick -n <commitid>`, and the changes will be applied to your working directory and staged in the index (like `git -a`), but will not be committed.

Comment: i accepted the other answer only because of the diagram and additional info, but your post is still very helpful.  Thanks!