# How to push one commit from one remote branch to another remote branch

Tags: git

The remote has two branches: `mainline` and `release-x`.

I pushed one recent feature from my local branch to remote `mainline`,
But I don't how to also push this feature into the `release-x` branch.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This should work for you: [git cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778375/git-apply-a-commit-on-another-branch-to-the-working-copy) the commit in your local repository, then push the change on remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

At first, make sure that you have the branches locally. This can be done by calling `git pull origin mainline` and `git pull origin release-x`.

### copy the commit

Go to `release-x` branch(check out a local copy) and copy the commit to that branch using `git cherry-pick <commit hash>`

Don't forget to execute `git push origin release-x` after that.

### merge it

You can also merge all changes from `mainline` to `release-x` by checking out `release-x` and runing `git merge release-x` or `git merge <commit hash>` if you want to merge the difference until a commit in `mainline`.

Don't forget to execute `git push origin release-x` after that.

### just push it

If you want to copy all changes from `mainline` to `release-x`, and `release-x` is 0 commits behind `mainline`, you can also push `mainline` to `release-x` using `git push origin mainline:release-x`

### overwrite it (***STRONGLY DISCOURAGED***)

You can also completely overwrite the remote content of `release-x` with the content of `mainline` using `git push -f origin mainline:release-x`. **But this will remove all changes made to `release` that are not committed in `mainline`**. If you want to do that despite this, I suggest you to use `--force-with-lease` as it does not overwrite the remote if another person pushed to it without you knowing.

Comment: For the first suggestion, what do you mean `Go to release-x branch`? You mean set up a local branch tracking remote `release-x`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full remote and branch to push to. The remote you cloned from is origin.

```
git push origin release-x
```

See "Pushing to Your Remotes" in [Working With Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in the Git Book.

This will only work if your local branch and `release-x` have a common ancestor. It may not be the best way to manage your release branch, it depends on your release process.